# Cross compiling a driver writtten in c for linux that doesnt come with configure file

Tags: linux, embedded, ethernet

We are trying to cross compile a driver for TP-Link TG 3468 gigabit ethernet adapter. The vendor has a linux version of the driver but there is no configure file present. There is just the make files and the c files. Please suggest a way to cross compile the driver.

We are trying to compile it for an ARM processor based single board computer.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of embedded Linux! :) This kind of thing is why folks who are experienced with it are in demand by tech recruiters.

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux kernel modules don't use autoconf, so have no configure files. Did you try to run `make` (perhaps with the appropriate `CC=` setting)?

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496047/841108).

Comment: we use the ./configure to give in the path for our dedicated compiler (cc=path parameter), before running make command.

Comment: Then try running `make CC=your-gcc-cross-compiler`

Comment: You'll probably need to be sure it gets pointed at the headers for the embedded kernel, not the host kernel.  Look through the build scripts, especially watch out for any utilization of 'uname'.  You might also consider building _on_ the target system.